# How to make a rest API With LAravel?

Tags: php, android, rest, laravel, guzzle

I want to develop a laravel web rest application.

I want to access this rest api with a android app. so how can i make it ?

I heared about the Guzzle http client for making rest api. How can i start with that ?

I just want the json array of valid /invalid format of a entry in database.

Anybody please help me ?

Comment: your question is too broad.

Comment: SO users are not here to write tutorials for you or do the coding for you. It's really up to you to search for a tutorial, do the coding and then come up with a specific problem you got stuck on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Simple Methord :

Working Fine For me.

```
$user= User::all()->toArray();
$post= Post::all()->toArray();
$comment= Comment:all()->toArray();

Response::json(array('user'=>$user,'post'=>$post,'comment'=>$comment));
```